# using a tag to replace div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my site has 2 pages both have hyperlinks to each other but when user click on that hyperlink I just need a certain div of that page to be replaced by certain div on other page, please guide me how to program it.

structure

page1.html

```
<div id="no_replace">
  <a href="page2.html">page 2</a>
  <div id="replace">
    //page one stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

page2.html

```
<div id="no_replace">
  <a href="page1.html">page 1</a>
  <div id="replace">
    //page two stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

so on page one when usr clicks on link "page two" ... I want the 'replace' div of page one to be replaced by 'replace' div of page2.html

Comment: please try to make more sense

Comment: learn: html > some server side language > javascript > ajax (this is the key!). good luck!

Comment: I thought his question was clear enough.  Look into `.load()`  You'll probably want to do something like:  `$('a#page_1').click(function(){ $("div#page_a_content").load('pageb.php div#page_b_content'); });`  When you click on a link on page a, it will load the #page_b_content div into the #page_a_content div via an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use javascript to trigger an event where the content of the div is replace when the button is clicks. Learn some javascript from w3schools.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosomething(){
 //replace div content here
}
</script>
<a href="somelink" onclick="dosomething();">
```