# using a tag to replace div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my site has 2 pages both have hyperlinks to each other but when user click on that hyperlink I just need a certain div of that page to be replaced by certain div on other page, please guide me how to program it.

structure

page1.html

```
<div id="no_replace">
  <a href="page2.html">page 2</a>
  <div id="replace">
    //page one stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

page2.html

```
<div id="no_replace">
  <a href="page1.html">page 1</a>
  <div id="replace">
    //page two stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

so on page one when usr clicks on link "page two" ... I want the 'replace' div of page one to be replaced by 'replace' div of page2.html and there should be fade in and fadeout

Comment: possible duplicate of [using a tag to replace div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766563/using-a-tag-to-replace-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the load() method.

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $('div').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: If you wanted it it fade in you would set the div's display property to 'none', or you could use .fadeOut().load([ABOVE CODE]).fadeIn();

Answer (score 0):

first give your link an id or class. I'm going to call it `.loadpage`

```
$('a.loadpage').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = $('#replace');
    div.fadeOut(300).load($(this).attr('href'), function(){ div.fadeIn(300); });
});
```

First you need to stop the default behavior of the link by doing `e.preventDefault()`. Then you need to use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load) method to bring in the contents of the page you're trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Page1.html

```
$(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $.get({url:"page2.html", 
           success: function(data){
           $("#replace").html($("#replace", $(data)).html());
     }
    });
  });
});
```